# How to dynamically add methods to a class?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[Here's a boiled down example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAFsBTfACzgBNcAuMAQQCcmBDATwB4CmBLbAOYA+MAF4wAbQDkAI1ZMpAGjCzWALykBdANzoMMVrlxgAYnDhgA3qgC+6UhWq4AdFDhMAoqwzkAFL4dKKnoefgEASjERazBTc2cAByY4fBT2BJIJQOpNMTAoAFdsDHxeHDBfSJiwAEgsPDgYEmd4AV8pbKolYjIg8N1Yuxt+oA) that fail with the error

`assignment of computed property/element. Indexable signature not found`

Surely flow can read the types and strings in the `methods` array. Why is it complaining?

Comment: a workaround would be to extend `Foo` from `Object` explicitly.

Comment: Why does that work? @ftor

Comment: Generally dynamically adding methods to something isn't a good idea. If you're going to use ES6 class sugar, you might as well make your class have a clear static API. You could still have those pass through to some dynamically-generated functions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow doesn't seem to allow indexable properties on custom class definitions. I don't know why, though.

AFAIK you have two workarounds:

Extend your class by `Object` explicitly.

```
/* @flow */

const methods: Array<string> = ['bar', 'baz'];

class Foo extends Object {}
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

methods.forEach((method: string) => {
  Foo.prototype[method] = function () {
    console.log('method', method);
  }
});
```

[Try it](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAFsBTfACzgBNcAuMAQQCcmBDATwB4CmBLbAOYA+MAF4wAbQDkAI1ZMpAGjCzWALykBdANzoMMVrlxgAYnDhgSAD3wlsNMAHkZAKxIZCAb1QBfdKQpqXAA6KDgmAFFWDHIACliAyip6Hn4BAEoxEW8wU3NggAcmOHwS9gKSCUTqTTEwKABXbA9eHDBYzJywAEgsPDgYEmD4AVipaqolYjIk9N1cvx85oA).

Or declare an indexable signature in an interface.

```
/* @flow */

interface Ix {
  [key: any]: any
}

class StrFunIx implements Ix {
  $key: string;
  $value: function;
}

class Foo extends StrFunIx {}

const methods: Array<string> = ['bar', 'baz'];

methods.forEach((method: string) => {
  Foo.prototype[method] = x => x;
});
```

[Try it](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gCSAHmAN6phgDaA1ngJ4BcYxWHAXR58OqAL7pSMYgGcZYAMo4CAMQCuWGmAwBbAA4w8OvLnlaGTACTtuYGcuwBzANyMwlgG7EYavDygapDgYcFiuEqhSsvIqcHBgeNT4WAAm8kqqGuYRpKH2YMY4ABZwaTwAggQExBwAPPYETgB8YAC8LADkAEbEBB0ANGDdxABeHQKuqIUlaQB0UHAEAKJkRQAUa9OlPA1OAJRtLRZgsXCzegRwOFccenjMWykCbWC0rS3U4XvOQA).

Comment: Seems like that method cannot be called on class instance.