# Add mixins to a class in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I can add mixins to function prototype, but seems like I can't do it with class prototype:

For example the [code](https://flow.org/try/#0G4QwTgBAtglgHjAdgZwgXggbwgEwPYDKUALgBYAUAlFgL4Q0BQDAZgK6IDGxMeiEAYlVoMA8gCMAVgFMuAOhDJkMAOaJy-WQAcweYroCemqQBpo8JMkoBuBoikB3AVVn4iZKjYYcANgtQBhYXFpOT8VNX8tHT1iQxMzBBRrWwcIf2dXEgprIA)

```
var mixins = { doSmth() {} }

function F() {}
Object.assign(F.prototype, mixins);
new F().doSmth();

class C {}
Object.assign(C.prototype, mixins);
new C().doSmth();
```

leads to these errors

```
8: Object.assign(C.prototype, mixins);
   ^ property `doSmth` of object literal. Property not found in
8: Object.assign(C.prototype, mixins);
                 ^ C
```

```
9: new C().doSmth();
           ^ property `doSmth`. Property not found in
9: new C().doSmth();
   ^ C
```

How can I add mixins to a class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically add methods to a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111896/how-to-dynamically-add-methods-to-a-class)

Comment: @MichaelDeBoey, that solution allows assignment, but the method cannot be called on class instance.